# There's an odd infinite scroll on my website after adding some JavaScript to the pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've added some JavaScript to my website that adds a glitter effect following the mouse as you move it and I absolutely love it. Except the fact that about halfway down the page a random new scroll bar appears and it scrolls past the footer and on forever. I can't seem to figure out what to add, or take out to make it stop scrolling past the footer. I've tried setting a max height for the body/html... I've tried taking out the "set scroll" function, I need it to stop scrolling on forever. I've also tried adding in the finish() method but I'm not exactly sure where it goes. Here is my code.

```
  var colour = "#ffffff";
            var sparkles = 200;
            var x = ox = 400;
            var y = oy = 300;
            var swide = 800;
            var shigh = 600;
            var sleft = sdown = 0;
            var tiny = new Array();
            var star = new Array();
            var starv = new Array();
            var starx = new Array();
            var stary = new Array();
            var tinyx = new Array();
            var tinyy = new Array();
            var tinyv = new Array();

            colours = new Array('#ffffff', '#cbaa89')

            n = 10;
            y = 0;
            x = 0;
            n6 = (document.getElementById && !document.all);
            ns = (document.layers);
            ie = (document.all);
            d = (ns || ie) ? 'document.' : 'document.getElementById("';
            a = (ns || n6) ? '' : 'all.';
            n6r = (n6) ? '")' : '';
            s = (ns) ? '' : '.style';

            if (ns) {
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    document.write('<layer name="dots' + i + '" top=0 left=0 width=' + i / 2 + ' height=' + i / 2 + ' bgcolor=#ff0000></layer>');
            }

            if (ie)
                document.write('<div id="con" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px"><div style="position:relative">');

            if (ie || n6) {
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    document.write('<div id="dots' + i + '" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:' + i / 2 + 'px;height:' + i / 2 + 'px;background:#ff0000;font-size:' + i / 2 + '"></div>');
            }

            if (ie)
                document.write('</div></div>');
            (ns || n6) ? window.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE): 0;

            function Mouse(evnt) {

                y = (ns || n6) ? evnt.pageY + 4 - window.pageYOffset : event.y + 4;
                x = (ns || n6) ? evnt.pageX + 1 : event.x + 1;
            }

            (ns) ? window.onMouseMove = Mouse: document.onmousemove = Mouse;

            function animate() {

                o = (ns || n6) ? window.pageYOffset : 0;

                if (ie) con.style.top = document.body.scrollTop + 'px';

                for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

                    var temp1 = eval(d + a + "dots" + i + n6r + s);

                    randcolours = colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];

                    (ns) ? temp1.bgColor = randcolours: temp1.background = randcolours;

                    if (i < n - 1) {

                        var temp2 = eval(d + a + "dots" + (i + 1) + n6r + s);
                        temp1.top = parseInt(temp2.top) + 'px';
                        temp1.left = parseInt(temp2.left) + 'px';

                    } else {

                        temp1.top = y + o + 'px';
                        temp1.left = x + 'px';
                    }
                }

                setTimeout("animate()", 10);
            }

            animate();

            window.onload = function() {
                if (document.getElementById) {
                    var i, rats, rlef, rdow;
                    for (var i = 0; i < sparkles; i++) {
                        var rats = createDiv(3, 3);
                        rats.style.visibility = "hidden";
                        rats.style.zIndex = "999";
                        document.body.appendChild(tiny[i] = rats);
                        starv[i] = 0;
                        tinyv[i] = 0;
                        var rats = createDiv(5, 5);
                        rats.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
                        rats.style.visibility = "hidden";
                        rats.style.zIndex = "999";
                        var rlef = createDiv(1, 5);
                        var rdow = createDiv(5, 1);
                        rats.appendChild(rlef);
                        rats.appendChild(rdow);
                        rlef.style.top = "2px";
                        rlef.style.left = "0px";
                        rdow.style.top = "0px";
                        rdow.style.left = "2px";
                        document.body.appendChild(star[i] = rats);
                    }
                    set_width();
                    sparkle();
                }
            }

            function sparkle() {
                var c;
                if (Math.abs(x - ox) > 1 || Math.abs(y - oy) > 1) {
                    ox = x;
                    oy = y;
                    for (c = 0; c < sparkles; c++)
                        if (!starv[c]) {
                            star[c].style.left = (starx[c] = x) + "px";
                            star[c].style.top = (stary[c] = y + 1) + "px";
                            star[c].style.clip = "rect(0px, 5px, 5px, 0px)";
                            star[c].childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor = star[c].childNodes[1].style.backgroundColor = (colour == "random") ? newColour() : colour;
                            star[c].style.visibility = "visible";
                            starv[c] = 50;
                            break;
                        }
                }
                for (c = 0; c < sparkles; c++) {
                    if (starv[c]) update_star(c);
                    if (tinyv[c]) update_tiny(c);
                }
                setTimeout("sparkle()", 40);
            }

            function update_star(i) {
                if (--starv[i] == 25) star[i].style.clip = "rect(1px, 4px, 4px, 1px)";
                if (starv[i]) {
                    stary[i] += 1 + Math.random() * 3;
                    starx[i] += (i % 5 - 2) / 5;
                    if (stary[i] < shigh + sdown) {
                        star[i].style.top = stary[i] + "px";
                        star[i].style.left = starx[i] + "px";
                    } else {
                        star[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
                        starv[i] = 0;
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    tinyv[i] = 50;
                    tiny[i].style.top = (tinyy[i] = stary[i]) + "px";
                    tiny[i].style.left = (tinyx[i] = starx[i]) + "px";
                    tiny[i].style.width = "2px";
                    tiny[i].style.height = "2px";
                    tiny[i].style.backgroundColor = star[i].childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor;
                    star[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
                    tiny[i].style.visibility = "visible"
                }
            }

            function update_tiny(i) {
                if (--tinyv[i] == 25) {
                    tiny[i].style.width = "1px";
                    tiny[i].style.height = "1px";
                }
                if (tinyv[i]) {
                    tinyy[i] += 1 + Math.random() * 3;
                    tinyx[i] += (i % 5 - 2) / 5;
                    if (tinyy[i] < shigh + sdown) {
                        tiny[i].style.top = tinyy[i] + "px";
                        tiny[i].style.left = tinyx[i] + "px";
                    } else {
                        tiny[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
                        tinyv[i] = 0;
                        return;
                    }
                } else tiny[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
            }

            document.onmousemove = mouse;

            function mouse(e) {
                if (e) {
                    y = e.pageY;
                    x = e.pageX;
                } else {
                    set_scroll();
                    y = event.y + sdown;
                    x = event.x + sleft;
                }

            }

            window.onscroll = set_scroll;

            function set_scroll() {
                if (typeof(self.pageYOffset) == 'number') {
                    sdown = self.pageYOffset;
                    sleft = self.pageXOffset;
                } else if (document.body && (document.body.scrollTop || document.body.scrollLeft)) {
                    sdown = document.body.scrollTop;
                    sleft = document.body.scrollLeft;
                } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollLeft)) {
                    sleft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                    sdown = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                } else {
                    sdown = 0;
                    sleft = 0;

                }

            }
            window.onresize = set_width;

            function set_width() {
                var sw_min = 999999;
                var sh_min = 999999;
                if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
                    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 0) sw_min = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                    if (document.documentElement.clientHeight > 0) sh_min = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
                }
                if (typeof(self.innerWidth) == 'number' && self.innerWidth) {
                    if (self.innerWidth > 0 && self.innerWidth < sw_min) sw_min = self.innerWidth;
                    if (self.innerHeight > 0 && self.innerHeight < sh_min) sh_min = self.innerHeight;
                }
                if (document.body.clientWidth) {
                    if (document.body.clientWidth > 0 && document.body.clientWidth < sw_min) sw_min = document.body.clientWidth;
                    if (document.body.clientHeight > 0 && document.body.clientHeight < sh_min) sh_min = document.body.clientHeight;
                }
                if (sw_min == 999999 || sh_min == 999999) {
                    sw_min = 800;
                    sh_min = 600;
                }
                swide = sw_min;
                shigh = sh_min;
            }

            function createDiv(height, width) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.style.position = "absolute";
                div.style.height = height + "px";
                div.style.width = width + "px";
                div.style.overflow = "hidden";
                return (div);
            }

            function newColour() {
                var c = new Array();
                c[0] = 255;
                c[1] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
                c[2] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (256 - c[1] / 2));
                c.sort(function() {
                    return (0.5 - Math.random());
                });
                return ("rgb(" + c[0] + ", " + c[1] + ", " + c[2] + ")");
            }
```

I've also made a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/5ydty5p2/

Comment: This is  very complicated script, maybe you would use some simpler one, like https://codepen.io/keerotic/pen/rOdgbr?

Comment: It is your sparkle effect, that animation slipping down and it makes growth you page height, hence you should stop your animation when scroll is close at the end of page stop animation,Note:if you give red your background color you can see, If I were you, I wouldn't use this animation because when user use this page each sparkle elements stay on page it will affect your page performance on bad way.

Comment: It's for a class assignment and will never be live. We have to get complicated script like this to work.

Comment: Can't I add a stop animation function then specify where? and if so... how would I do it?

Comment: Love the support for Netscape 4. Takes me back.

Answer (score 0):

it's the sparkles that are wrongly positioned. If you take a look at the inspector (`F12` you'll see them animating). The calculated position is incorrected and since they're created directly in the body they make it grow, and grow...

Since the whole script is a hack you could further hack it with a `max-height` property on the body...

Having sparkless is nice but you should really look for an alternative, this piece of JS is awful. And there is no jquery involved here, it's merely divs following the mouse. You should look for a proper plugin.